Sci-fi movie from the early 2000s with giant spiders, in which a lady goes into the jungle or forest looking for her lost partner or lost soldiers
I have spent years trying to figure what movie I watched when I was a child.
The only memorable scene was where a lady goes into the jungle or forest looking for her lost partner or lost soldiers. She then finds a soldier’s skeleton up in the tree which revealed to be one of the missing people. I cannot remember if he was covered in spider webs or not, but it was definitely a soldier up in the trees with a name tag.
It is definitely not Jurassic Park. I did remember there being giant spiders too. Please help my poor soul.

Is this Arachnid (2001)...?

A scientific expedition investigating the outbreak of an unknown viral epidemic on an island in the south Pacific battles with a giant alien spider in the jungle.

A female pilot named Loren Mercer is hired to fly a medical expedition to a South Pacific island. She's also looking for her brother, a US Navy fighter pilot who went missing in this region ten months earlier. Unbeknownst to her and the others, an alien spacecraft previously crashed on the island, which is now home to a giant spider and other mutated bugs.
Around 57 minutes into the film, Loren and some of the others find her brother's decomposed corpse hanging from a tree on the island. Much of his skeleton is exposed and his name tag is clearly visible on what's left of his uniform. The tree is also draped with spider webs.


Arachnid (2001)




